# Why program throws runtime error while iterating over an emtpy vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector <int> o;    //Empty vector
for(int i=0;i<=o.size()-1;i++) cout<<o[i];
```

got runtime error in the above

```
vector <int> o;  
for(auto j : o){
 cout<<j<<" ";
            }
```

However this code runs fine if **iterator** is used instead

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `o.size()` and what happens if you subtract 1 from it if it's already zero?

Comment: That's probably because `std::vector::size()` is unsigned, so if vector is empty, `o.size()-1`doesn't result in `-1`, but rolls over into a huge value.

Comment: Debugging step 1: verify that the loop limit is what you're assuming with `cout << o.size() - 1 << endl;`

Comment: `i<=o.size()-1` --> `i<o.size()`

Answer (score 14):

`o.size()` is required by the C++ standard to return an `unsigned` type. When that's zero, subtracting 1 yields `std::numeric_limits<decltype(o.size())>::max()` which means your loop runs past the bounds of the empty vector.

`for(std::size_t i = 0; i < o.size(); ++i)` is the obvious fix. The use of `<=` and `-1` seems almost disingenuously contrived to me.

Comment: `<=` with `-1` happens a lot with beginners. They try to use a `for` loop with `<=`, discover the off-by-one error and fix it by adding `-1`.

Comment: Thanks sir I was unaware that it returns unsigned integer.

Answer (score 6):

`o.size()` will return an unsigned value of 0.  Subtracting one from it returns a very large positive number, essentially making an infinite loop.  Eventually your out-of-bounds array accesses to `o[i]` will result in a crash.

You could use

```
for(int i = 0; i <= int(o.size() - 1); i++)
```

Or just use the more typical

```
for(int i = 0;i < o.size(); i++)
```

where you check for "less than", not "less or equal" to a number one less.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, because math with unsigned values is done modulo 2<sup>N</sup> and the integral conversion will give a result congruent to the source integer, which will be -1 for 2s complement.

Comment: I would not even mention `i <= int(o.size() - 1)` as a possible solution.

Comment: It's not undefined what `int(o.size() - 1` is, it's **implementation defined**. Quote from `[conv.integral]/3` (C++17)  _If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined_

Comment: @ChrisMM: Thanks very much, I'll remove my first comment - it has too many "likes" and could therefore mislead.

Comment: @ChrisMM There's different wording in N4849 (C++ 20 draft) _the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer
modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the width of the destination type_

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I believe C++20 has been updated in a few places (such as this) to include what implementations do anyway -- I **think** it also makes two's complement mandatory. The quote I did was for C++17, which is still the latest released version.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, it is the result of two's complement becoming mandatory in C++20 due to [P0907R4
Signed Integers are Two’s Complement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since `sizeof(size_t)` is greater or equal than `sizeof(int)` (although this might be implementation dependent) and `size_t` is `unsigned`, the `int` (`1`) is converted to `size_t`.

Therefore, in the expression `o.size() - 1`, the `1` is implicitly converted to `size_t`, and `o.size() - 1` (which is equivalent to `size_t(0 - 1)`) becomes equal to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`. Therefore, the `for` loop is entered and accessing your empty `o` at index `0` results in undefined behavior.

You should:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < o.size(); ++idx) { /* ... */ }
```

If for some reason you need the index to be of type `int`, you can:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < static_cast<int>(o.size()); ++idx) { /* ... */ }
```

or in your example (which is less common):

```
for (int idx = 0; idx <= static_cast<int>(o.size()) - 1; ++idx) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: "sizeof(size_t) is greater than sizeof(int)" can be "sizeof(size_t) is greater than or equal to sizeof(int) and size_t is unsigned". That would improve this answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks, I changed "the -1" to "the 1" is implicitly converted to size_t

Comment: `size_t(0-1)` is not undefined. From `[conv.integral]/2]`, _If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)_